# Plotting rectangles to Plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to plot the ranges in my histogram to a Plotly graph. I would like the rectangles to be in green colors with the opacity adjusted according to the relative_Frequency (higher RF should be darker).

I tried the below, but it's messing up my graph - any ideas?

```
hist_df.head()

low         high     counts relative_frequency
18122.98    18322.98    20  0.010199
19722.98    19922.98    22  0.011219
19922.98    20122.98    21  0.010709
20122.98    20322.98    21  0.010709
20322.98    20522.98    27  0.013768
```

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Define los colores para las distintas tonalidades de verde
colors = px.colors.sequential.Greens[::-1]

fig = go.Figure()

# Agrega la línea del gráfico original
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['Close']))

# Recorre los rangos del histograma y sombrea las zonas según la frecuencia relativa
for i, row in hist_df.iterrows():
    color_idx = int(row['relative_frequency'] * (len(colors) - 1))
    color = colors[color_idx]
    fig.add_shape(type='rect',
                  x0=row['low'], y0=0,
                  x1=row['high'], y1=1,
                  fillcolor=color,
                  line=dict(width=0))

fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Date', yaxis_title='Price')
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True)

fig.show(config={'scrollZoom': True})
```

Graphs

[Original graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rphi.png)

[After adding the code to plot the rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkjKS.png)

Comment: I think this example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes) will help you with what you have realized. x-axis is a time series, so it should be specified in chronological order.